# Mongoose update previously fetched collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to update a collection. Docs seem unclear on this.

I am wondering how to achieve the following:

```
Order.find({ _id: { $in: ids }}).exec(function(err, items, count) {
  // Following gives error - same with save()
  items.update({ status: 'processed'}, function(err, docs) {

  });
});
```

I know how to batch save like this:

```
Model.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, { multi: true }, callback);
```

But that requires setting my query again.

I've also tried:

```
Order.collection.update(items...
```

But that throws a max call stack error.

Answer (score 0):

In `mongoose`, `model.find(callback)`, return an `Array` of `Document` via callback. You can call `save` on a `Document` but not on an `Array`. So you can use `for loop` or `forEach` on the `Array`.

```
 Order
 .find({ _id: { $in: ids}})
 .exec(function(err, items, count) {
    items.forEach(function (it) {
        it.save(function () {
            console.log('you have saved ', it)
        });
    })
 });
```

Comment: Yes thanks - I know how to do that. Wondering about collection update specifically. Currently using the Model.save above which let's me do it all on one line but I do have to query again. The question is more on learning some inner workings of Mongoose